# Api call works with curl but not with google apps script, what am I missing?

Tags: google-apps-script

So this part works:

```
function authenticateToggl()
{ 
  url = "https://api.track.toggl.com/api/v8/me";

  //Put it all together.
  var options =
  {
      'method'     : 'get',    
      'headers'    : {"Authorization": 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode('email@gmail.com:mypassword')},     
  };

  //Make Login call to When I work.
  var responseGetPlan = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var strResponseGetPlan = responseGetPlan.getContentText();
  Logger.log('Get Plan Response: ' + strResponseGetPlan); //Log response.

  var parsedData = JSON.parse(strResponseGetPlan); //Parse into JSON format.
  var strId = parsedData.data.api_token;
  return strId;
}
```

That returned me a string api token, which I can use in api curl calls like this:

```
curl -v -u c8f4c3TOKENe5a580bfeab:api_token -X GET https://api.track.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces/1001455/projects
```

Doing that I appropriately got back my list of projects per the api docs.

But when I tried to translate that into google apps script, it fails. I'm sure it is that my header is formatted wrong?

```
    function nextStep(){
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.track.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces/1001455/projects', {//
    'headers': {'Authorization': "Basic c8f4c3TOKENe5a580bfeab:api_token"},
    'method':'get'
});
}
```

I get back a 403 authentication error. Does the word basic not apply here? using the same url, method, and token.

Comment: I can just resend the authenticating header from the first part over and over, but I explicitly want to know how to use the api token.

Comment: Look up Basic Authentication. The following link should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to convert your string token to [base64 encoding](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata_1),

```
function nextStep(){
  //API Key requires base64 encoding. Use Google Apps Scripts built in method
  var base64token = Utilities.base64Encode("c8f4c3TOKENe5a580bfeab:api_token"); 
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.track.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces/1001455/projects', {
         'headers': {'Authorization': "Basic "+base64token},
         'method':'get'
    });
}
```

**Additional References:**

[Github - Google-Apps-Scripts-Toggl-Request](https://github.com/crgriffiths/Google-Apps-Scripts-Toggl-Request/blob/master/togglRequest.gs)

[Github - toggl-appscript](https://github.com/aero82-zz/toggl-appscript/blob/master/toggle_appscript.js)

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered an issue using this solution. I wasn't able to replicate your issue due to my limited resources